Recurring billing transaction 'Trans Status' from Authorize.net differs from the API ARBGetSubscriptionRequest response
I’m using “ARBGetSubscriptionRequest” to get information about the recurring billing transaction: $response->getSubscription()->getArbTransactions(). Depending on the “Trans Status,” I grant access to my client service or not.
By using ARBGetSubscriptionRequest, I got a transaction response “This transaction has been approved”, but in fact, it was not. The Authorize.net website indicated that the transaction status was “voided.”
i considered " “This transaction has been approved” was final.
So, my question is: if it’s not a proper way to validate that the transaction was committed (no way back), then what would be the proper way to validate that the recurring subscription payment was completed?
